# Save Android ListView items while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

my problem is. I'm having a ListView with a random number of rows (15 to 30).
I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter to display the rows. Each row contains a seekbar, TextViews and switches.
When I move the seekbar(progress) I change text of some TextViews.
When I scroll down so the seekbar isn't visible anymore, they get reloaded from scratch and the TextViews as well as the seekbar progress and switch state is set to default again.

Is it easily possible to save the whole ListView state, so the edited rows doesn't lose data when scrolling up and down?

I'm using a holder class in my CustomAdapter

```
private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_owner;
        TextView tv_preset;
        SeekBar seekbar;
        Switch switch;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MyListViewItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_123, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.tv_owner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_var_owner);
            holder.tv_preset = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_var_preset);
            holder.seekbar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            holder.switch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        final Resources res = activity.getResources();

        holder.seekbar.setMax(1000);

        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

            @Override       
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
            }       

            @Override       
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
            }       

            @Override       
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
                holder.tv_owner.setText(String.valueOf(holder.seekbar.getProgress()));
                holder.tv_preset.setText("$ " + holder.seekbar.getProgress()*0.5;
            }       
        });          
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to maintain the state.

1) Create a POJO class & ArrayList of object and manage value from it, so that each time when your row is created it will get the value from the respected object, which help to manage the proper data.

2) Don't recycle your view. I.e. create your itemView -> holderView each for each row and manage rather than recycling it. 
**Note: This method is not recommended ever this is just a way to solve your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Adapter just convert you data to view items. The most easiest cases it cache all data inside adapter or persist somewhere (DB/Server/File/SharedPreference or other) to save changes an show them again when user open this screen again later or just change screen orientation. The way of data saving depends on particular use case and can vary. And ViewHolder is not a place to save values because it's reused with different MyListViewItem and main reason why it exist - just hold views and not find it all the time when we try to reuse view again that helps to increase ListView scrolling speed.

In your case you can save progress value into MyListViewItem. In you case just do something like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
   ...
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_owner;
        TextView tv_preset;
        SeekBar seekbar;
        Switch switch;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MyListViewItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_123, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.tv_owner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_var_owner);
            holder.tv_preset = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_var_preset);
            holder.seekbar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            holder.switch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Resources res = activity.getResources();

        holder.seekbar.setMax(1000);
        holder.seekbar.setProgress(rowItem.getProgress());
        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

            @Override       
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
            }       

            @Override       
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
            }       

            @Override       
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                rowItem.setProgress(progress);          
                holder.tv_preset.setText("$ " + progress*0.5;
            }       
        });          
        return convertView;
    }
}
```